# Imputing entirely missing rows omics data

Tags: r, missing-data, paired-data

I have a dataset of 153 observations and 84 variables. The dataset is processed for a classification issue.
Observation are three time repeated measures of radiomics in 3 different regions of a soft tissu component in the same patient.

By the 84 variables, there is 53 radiomic parameters and 31 clinic parameters.
Three entirely rows in three different patient are missing. There is also some missing data in the other clinical variables.
As I would like to not na.omit the missing rows, and would like to use a NA's-non friendly classifier (Lasso if I could find a method to paired observations-Lasso), I'm trying to handle missing values.
I've tried without success use KnnImpute from caret package

```r
require(caret)
require(RANN)

preProcValues <- preProcess(data %>% 
                          dplyr::select(names of clinical variables),
                            method = c("knnImpute"),
                            k = 10,
                            knnSummary = mean)
impute_data <- predict(preProcValues, data,na.action = na.pass)
```

And MICE:

```r
require(mice)

impute_data <- mice(data, m=5, maxit=50, meth='pmm', seed=500)
```

Comment: By "missing complete rows" do you really mean that there is no data at all for this three patients?

Comment: Yes, completely no data for the omics parameters for three regions of measurement in three individuals.

Comment: But you have the clinic parameters?

Comment: Yes les than 10% of the clinic parameters are missing, and for the 3 rows only 4 clinical parameters of the 31 clinical parameters are missing.